# Javascript stringed array into an actual array

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-textext

Ok. So the title sounds confusing but that's probably the best way to describe it.

I'm using the [TextExt jQuery plugin](http://textextjs.com/) to create a tag list in a form. However the plugin creates an array in a string when submitted. eg. `"["this","that","other"]"`.

How can I convert this to an actual array? `["this","that","other"]`

Cue really simple answer I completely overlooked.

Comment: You could `eval`, but that would be evil. :)

Comment: You could try to parse it with a javascript json parser, such as found at http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Are you sure the plug-in doesn't provide that array somewhere?

Comment: he is using jQuery which has a built in JSON parser: jQuery.parseJSON()

Comment: JSON parsing assumes valid JSON will be provided. If the plugin doesn't guarantee it, `eval` may be safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery you can just pass it through [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/%20%22parseJSON) like this:

```
var array = jQuery.parseJSON('["this","that","other"]')
```

Comment: There's that simple answer I completely overlooked!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [JSON](http://json.org/). So then use `JSON.parse()`, or better [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) when you already have jQuery inlcuded.